# Windows - PHP - 'bin\behat' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: php, windows, behat

So I'm trying to run a test on my framework on Windows 10 after a git clone but I keep getting these issues.
Here's what I tried and the results:

1."bin/behat" in terminal - **'bin' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.**
2. "bin\behat" in terminal - **'bin\behat' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.**
3. "php bin/behat" or "php bin\behat" in terminal -

```
**dir=$(d=${0%[/\\]*}; cd "$d"; cd "../vendor/behat/behat/bin" && pwd)
# See if we are running in Cygwin by checking for cygpath program
if command -v 'cygpath' >/dev/null 2>&1; then
# Cygwin paths start with /cygdrive/ which will break windows PHP,
# so we need to translate the dir path to windows format. However
# we could be using cygwin PHP which does not require this, so we
# test if the path to PHP starts with /cygdrive/ rather than /usr/bin
if [[ $(which php) == /cygdrive/* ]]; then
dir=$(cygpath -m $dir);
fi
fi
dir=$(echo $dir | sed 's/ /\ /g')
"${dir}/behat" "$@"**
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Make sure Behat is installed - you have a vendor directory
2. If not installed run install command
3. Make sure you are running from the right directory - the one that contains `composer.json`
4. Make sure you are using the right separator based on the command line you are using - look in the command line and see what type it is used `/` or `\`